# Creating large base map quickly

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdal-translate, mbtiles

I'm new in map. I try to create map tile. I start with `GeoJSON` and using `QGIS 3` to parse it into `PNG tile`. But when I add more data in layer, I have to run it from beginning. It very slow in `zoom level` 20.

Then, I split data into smaller cluster. I create `mbtile` instead `png tile`. But when I use `tile-join` to merge this mbtiles, it shown `core dumped`. And if I using `gdal-translate` to convert it to tif file type, it return large file and time to merge still to long.

Because I never done it before, I think I do wrong way. I don't know how can some company like Google, Here Map can create very large base map.

Comment: they use a lot of small computers to do it in parallel.

Comment: @ian-turton So, how to split it for parallel processing. I mean, can I split a large map into multi small square box without overlap and then create png tile for these box?

Comment: basically, yes that is exactly how it is done (though you usually need some overlap to handle edge cases like labels and symbols)